# Add elements to a JList from class external to the GUI

Tags: java, swing, object

I've created an application that attaches events to a class of `JButtons` and other swing components that I instantiate many times in the GUI class.

The class `MenuItemEventHandler` is attached to each menu item.

I'm finding it difficult to find a solution to this. It's probably staring me in the face. My initial solution was to put the buttons event handlers in the GUI class and change the fields of the GUI class to display additional list items. Or even passing a `JList` from the `MenuItemEventHandler` class to the GUI, but I can't quite seem to find a proper solution. I've trawled the web to find people discussing MVC's. I'm not sure I require that level of depth.

Below is a class that creates the button part of a menu item, this has the `ButtonEventHandler` attached to it.

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    private JButton addFood;
    private String foodName;

    // food name was passed in by another class.    
    public void createButtons()  
    {
        JButton newButton = new JButton();

        newButton.setBounds(260, 157, 40,30);

        MenuItemEventHandler action = new MenuItemEventHandler(this.foodName);

        newButton.setAction(action);
        this.addFood = newButton;
    }

    public JButton getAddFoodButton() 
    {
        return this.addFood;
    }   
}
```

Handles the events for each button instantiated in the GUI.

```
public class MenuItemEventHandler extends AbstractAction 
{
    private String menuItemName;
    private DefaultListModel<String> orderedFood;

    public MenuItemEventHandler(String foodName) 
    {
        this.menuItemName = foodName;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        /* button clicked add this objects food name to the list
         * on the gui.
         * 
         */ 
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GUI2Test 
{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JList<String> orderList;
    public DefaultListModel<String> orderedFood;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new GUI2Test();
            }
        });
    }

    public GUI2Test()  
    {
        createForm();
        createList();

        /*
        *  would normaly loop to create multiple panels 
        */
        MenuItem button1 = new MenuItem();

        button1.createButtons();    
        frame.add(button1.getAddFoodButton());
        frame.add(orderList);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createList() 
    {
        orderedFood = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        orderList = new JList<String>(orderedFood);
        orderList.setBounds(20, 140, 200, 400);
        orderList.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        orderList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        orderList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        orderedFood.addElement("test");
    }

    public void createForm() 
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Resturant");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I use gridlayout in my real version I took it out mistakenly when shortening my code.

Comment: So long as your aware of the issues ;)

Comment: Yeah thanks, might quickly add it in I'm quite poor at communicating what i'm trying to achieve just in words.

Comment: The reality is, your `MenuItemEventHandler` is going to need a reference to something (I'd say the controller), so that when triggered, it can alert the responsible element to the event. I'd start by defining what ever is going to handle this event as an `interface` to further decouple the code...